# Sympy - How to declare mathematical Symbol with any LaTeX string

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I would like to declare a Sympy symbol, that looks like `C_{x_{0}}` when displayed as a LaTeX string.

I have tested the following

```
from sympy import Symbol, latex
Cx0=Symbol('{C_{x_{0}}')
latex(Cx0)
```

However, the result is not as expected, the second underscore is not present. I obtain

```
'{C_{{x {0}}}'
```

Does anyone has a clue on how to display any mathematical LaTeX expression?

Comment: Try `mySym = Symbol("C_x_0")` followed by `latex(mySym, mode="equation")`.

Comment: I have tried it, however this is not working. I still have the same wrong result.`import sympy; sympy.latex(sympy.Symbol('C_x_0'), mode='equation')` -> `'\\begin{equation}C_{x 0}\\end{equation}'`

Comment: I'm on a device where I can't test this out, but (on the top of my head, since no one else have answered you yet) can you possibly first define C_x as: `Cx = Symbol("C_x")` and thereafter create C_x_0 as `Cx0 = Symbol("Cx_0")`?

Comment: Thanks for this proposition,however it does not work. I have posted a bug on [github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10489)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed in version 1.0 of `sympy`

The following commands

```
from sympy import Symbol, latex
Cx0=Symbol('{C_{x_{0}}')
latex(Cx0)
```

return

```
'{C_{x_0}}'
```